# How do I enable CORS for custom route in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cors, sails.js

I have an Angular 1.x app that calls APIs in my Sails.js app. Whenever I try to call the APIs from my Angular app, I get this -

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:1337/portal/login. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value ''. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.`

Since my Sails.js app has a lot of other APIs which wont be used on this Angular app, I dont wanna apply CORS on all of them by setting `allRoutes: true` in config/cors.js. So I followed the documentation of Sails.js and have written custom CORS config in this way -

```
    '/portal/login': {
        target: 'MyController.login',
        cors: {
            origin: '*',
            credentials: true,
            methods: 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD, PATCH',
            headers: 'content-type, Authorization'
        }
    }
```

But it doesnt work. If I enable `allRoutes: true` then it starts working but I dont want to enable CORS on all my routes and expose them. I have tried every possible combination of `origin, credentials, methods, headers` but it always gives the same error.

Can you please help me resolving this? 
Thankz in advance.

Comment: If you look at the developer tools in your browser, can you see how the CORS data is being sent?  Use that to validate you're getting the right challenge/response entries in your request and response. There are some  [good resources](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) to help you better understand CORS. It's worth the effort to read as understanding CORS will help you a lot, it's not difficult once you get the jist of it.

Comment: Did you try to have a look at the docs? Seems to cover this exact point: http://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/security/cors#?configuring-cors-for-individual-routes

Comment: This problem was solved in:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65366607/sails-react-and-axios-error-with-cors-policy-no-access-control-allow-origin/66607805#66607805

Answer (score 0):

In **/config/http.js** file, uncomment the 'order' array fragment and add header params inside myRequestLogger method.

```
order: [
  'startRequestTimer',
  'cookieParser',
  'session',
  'myRequestLogger',
  'bodyParser',
  'handleBodyParserError',
  'compress',
  'methodOverride',
  'poweredBy',
  '$custom',
  'router',
  'www',
  'favicon',
  '404',
  '500'
],


 myRequestLogger: function (req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD');
  res.header('Allow', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD');
  res.header('X-Powered-By', '');
  return next();
},
```

inside **/config/cors.js** (sails v0.12) or **/config/security.js** (sails v1.x) add the following code snippet

```
module.exports.security = { //sails v1.x, if is sails v0.12 change security for cors
  allRoutes: true,
  allowOrigins: '*',
  allowCredentials: false,
  allowRequestMethods: 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS,HEAD',
  allowRequestHeaders: 'content-type'
}
```

In case none of this works (which I find difficult to happen), add in the return of your **controller** method (but, I think it is not necessary):

```
return res.set({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  }).json({ status: true, //body });
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me in     \config\security.js

```
cors: {
allRoutes: true,
    allowOrigins: [
  'http://localhost:1337',
  'http://localhost:8100',
  'http://localhost',
    ],
    allowCredentials: true,
    allowRequestHeaders:'content-type'
//allowCredentials: false
```

},

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -2):

You can do it by enabling CORS in the `Sails.js` security file inside the config folder:

```
config/security.js
```

Here's the code for it:

```
cors: {
    allRoutes: true,
    allowOrigins: '*',
    allowCredentials: false,
}
```

You can check out the reference for it on `Sails.js` official documentation:
https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/security/cors

Comment: The question says: "If I enable allRoutes: true then it starts working but I dont want to enable CORS on all my routes and expose them"